# Simple fade in fade out div with jquery on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, hide, fade

THIS CODE UNDER HERE WORKS, you can read the answers under here - i edit this for future reference.

**HTML**:

```
<div><a href="#" id="btn">Show bank div and hide fancy div</a></div>
<div id="btn-bk"><a href="#">back</a></div>
<div id="bank">Bank Div</div>
<div id="fancy">Fancy Div</div>
```

**CSS**:

```
#bank {display:none;}
#btn-bk {display:none;}
```

**Javascript**:

```
    $('#btn').click(function(e){    
    $('#fancy, #btn').fadeOut('slow', function(){
        $('#bank, #btn-bk').fadeIn('slow');
    });
});

    $('#btn-bk').click(function(e){    
        $('#bank, #btn-bk').fadeOut('slow', function(){
            $('#fancy, #btn').fadeIn('slow');
        });
    });
```

[Live DEMO that works](http://jsfiddle.net/3XwZv/71/)

Comment: please include all the code in the question in case the jsfiddle disappears.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your problem is with this line of code:

```
$('#bank').replace('<div id="fancy"></div>').fadeIn('slow');
```

There is no .replace() function in jQuery.  Remove that and it works:

```
$('#bank').fadeIn('slow');
```

See it here:  http://jsfiddle.net/3XwZv/57/

Comment: Beat me to it :) +1 for speed

Comment: Argh!! Awesome... I have been trying so long now, could not understand why it wasnt showing the BANK... Cheers man! 

Thx again

Comment: There *is* a .replace() function, is that what you were looking for?  Check out the docs at http://docs.jquery.com/, they are very helpful.  I often just scan the categories of functions and see if they have what I want.  Reading about interesting sounding functions will teach you a lot.

Answer (score 3):

Use the following jQuery code:

```
$('#btn').click(function(e){    
    $('#fancy').fadeOut('slow', function(){
        $('#bank').fadeIn('slow');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use html () instead of replace(). Also, assuming you want to replace your bank div with the following html:

```
<div id="fancy"></div>
```

Try this

```
$('#btn').click(function(e){    
    $('#fancy').fadeOut('slow', function(){
        $('#bank').html('<div id="fancy"></div>').fadeIn('slow');
    });
});
```

Comment: I actually stumpled upon another issue - i need a back button, so when its clicked, the bank fade out again and then the fancy fade in again... Is this easy to implement? If possible, i would appreciate if you could add it to the fiddle?

Comment: not sure is this is what u wanted.. but u can give it a try..

http://jsfiddle.net/3XwZv/62/