# Fade out and remove a <div>

Tags: removeclass, fadeout

How can I fade out the following?
It does also need to be removed completely, not just only alpha 0 but also display:none and visibility:hidden after the fade out.

FIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/fourroses666/ywMUx/2/

js:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $('.go-away').click(function() {
      $('.message').removeClass('show');
  });
</script>
```

css:

```
<style>
  .message{display:none; visibility:hidden;}
  .message.show{display:block; visibility:visible;}
  .go-away{float:right; cursor:pointer; cursor:hand;}
</style>
```

html:

```
<div class="message show">Pizza is nice! <div class="go-away">x</div></div>
```

Comment: This can easily be modified to just fade out.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12584481/simple-fade-in-fade-out-div-with-jquery-on-click

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
$('.go-away').click(function() {
    $(this).parent().fadeOut();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`fadeOut` makes it invisible, the `400` is how many milliseconds to fade out over, and then `function() { $(this).remove() }` is the callback function (called after the fadeOut animation has completed) that will remove the element from the DOM. Here's a working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/asifrc/ywMUx/3/). Let me know if this helps or if you have any questions :)

```
  $('.go-away').click(function() {
      $('.message').fadeOut(400, function() {
          $(this).remove();
      });
  });
```