# FadeIn and fadeOut effect on onclick function

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick, fadein, fadeout

Is it possible *fadeIn*, *fadeOut* or other effect on `onclick` function?

E.G. When click

```
<a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('test').style.backgroundImage='url(img/test.jpg)'" ><span class="left">Test</span>></a>
```

change background within fade effect?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12584481/simple-fade-in-fade-out-div-with-jquery-on-click

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this style:

```
<style>
#test {

transition: background .1s linear;
-webkit-transition: background .1s linear;
-moz-transition: background .1s linear;
-o-transition: background .1s linear;

}
</style>

<a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('test').style.backgroundImage='url(img/test.jpg)'" ><span class="left">Test</span>></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="javascript:changeBackground('img/test.jpg')"><span class="left">Test</span>></a>
<div id="test" style="display: none;"></div>
<script>
    function changeBackground(src) {
        var img = new Image();
        img.src = src;
        img.onload = function () {
            $('#test').fadeIn();
        }
    }
</script>
```

**You can do it with jQuery**