# jQuery fade in fade out div on click with more than 2 divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, fade

I'm trying to create a jQuery fade in/out banner for a website that has 3 different links on it. I have successfully used the following answer [Simple fade in fade out div with jquery on click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12584481/simple-fade-in-fade-out-div-with-jquery-on-click) to get 2 of the links to work but I'm having trouble with the third.
Here is the jQuery code:

```
$('#btn2').click(function (e) {
    $('#home_splash1').fadeOut('slow', function () {
        $('#home_splash2').fadeIn('slow');
    });
});

$('#btn1').click(function (e) {
    $('#home_splash2').fadeOut('slow', function () {
        $('#home_splash1').fadeIn('slow');
    });
});

$('#btn3').click(function (e) {
    $('#home_splash1').fadeOut('slow', function () {
        $('#home_splash3').fadeIn('slow');
    });
});
```

The HTML/CSS code is pretty lengthy, so I'll post the link to jsfiddle, which has all the code http://jsfiddle.net/u2NGy/ 
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: what is the issue exactly?

Comment: I wanted the links to fade out the active div and fade in each link's corresponding div. It was working well between #btn1 & #btn2, but #btn3 only worked from #btn1 and then it would stop working. I solved it by removing the duplicate id's per Sneaky's suggestion. Also, I used kamilkp's fix as well. Thanks guys!Here is the updated working code: http://jsfiddle.net/arZMC/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have duplicate id's on your page, which is not valid HTML:

```
<a href="#" class="white" id="btn3">Trusted Quality</a>
```

I'm guessing jQuery either fails to run, or just runs on the first element it finds that matches the id.  Try changing the id's so that they are unique and it should get you closer.

Answer (score 1):

You need to write

```
$('#btn2').click(function(e){    
    $('#home_splash1, #home_splash3').fadeOut('slow', function(){
        $('#home_splash2').fadeIn('slow');
    });
});
```

instead of

```
$('#btn2').click(function(e){    
    $('#home_splash1', '#home_splash3').fadeOut('slow', function(){
        $('#home_splash2').fadeIn('slow');
    });
});
```

Also you had two anchors with `id="btn3"`. I updated your fiddle, it now works: http://jsfiddle.net/vD77F/31/