# Fade div in and out with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, fade

I'm losing my mind here.....

I wanted to fade in and out a div on the same page. I don't know JQuery so I started searching the thing I wanted.

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12584481/simple-fade-in-fade-out-div-with-jquery-on-click). It does exactly what I want it to do (in the Fiddle).

So I started copying and stuff but I just won't work

Here is what I did....

In my `<head>` I added the JQuery and CSS style

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#btn').click(function(e){    
    $('#fancy, #btn').fadeOut('slow', function(){
        $('#bank, #btn-bk').fadeIn('slow');
    });
});

$('#btn-bk').click(function(e){    
    $('#bank, #btn-bk').fadeOut('slow', function(){
        $('#fancy, #btn').fadeIn('slow');
    });
});
</script>
<style>
#bank {display:none;}
#btn-bk {display:none;}
</style>
```

In the body I placed the HTML

```
<div><a href="#" id="btn">Show bank div and hide fancy div</a></div>
<div id="btn-bk"><a href="#">back</a></div>
<div id="bank">Bank Div</div>
<div id="fancy">Fancy Div</div>
```

It does nothing. I don't see what I'm doing wrong!

M.

Comment: it works fine do you get any error

Comment: Try to placing the `jQuery` and the `<script>` at the end of your `body`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The one difference is their methods are defined in the jquery onload method. When JQuery tries to bind to the elements, they're not actually there yet! Try wrapping your Javascript like this...

```
$(window).load(function(){
$('#btn').click(function(e){    
    $('#fancy, #btn').fadeOut('slow', function(){
        $('#bank, #btn-bk').fadeIn('slow');
    });
});

$('#btn-bk').click(function(e){    
    $('#bank, #btn-bk').fadeOut('slow', function(){
        $('#fancy, #btn').fadeIn('slow');
    });
});
});
```

Comment: No problem @Interactive, if you think one of our answers helped you please also mark either as "accepted" to help other users and keep the sites unanswered questions count down. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Wrap your JS code in a **document.ready** statement:

```
$(function () {
    $('#btn').click(function(e){
        $('#fancy, #btn').fadeOut('slow', function(){
            $('#bank, #btn-bk').fadeIn('slow');
        });
    });

    $('#btn-bk').click(function(e){
        $('#bank, #btn-bk').fadeOut('slow', function(){
            $('#fancy, #btn').fadeIn('slow');
        });
    });
});
```

What it will actually do, is it will wait until your **Document Object Model (DOM)** is ready for Javascript to be executed.

You can use **$(window).load({})**, but in that case your entire page, include images and iframes, will be fully downloaded, and only **THEN** your Javascript will run ([Source](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/))

It's okay on a simple pages, but on a more complex occasions it will make you a headache.

Comment: This one is better ans for me.

Comment: @Interactive you welcome. If you have a any more question, I can help you futher

Answer (score 1):

It does nothing because you placed your code in the head, and you're not waiting for the page to load, and when it executes, the selectors (for example `$('#btn')`) return empty object. Either:

1. Move you code below `</body>`.
2. Use jQuery "on load" handler (`$()`).